# Why does Excel NOT fail when wrapped around AND?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet whereby data should only be entered in one column.  If data is entered in *both* column cells, then an error should show.  I created a simple formula to do this validation that works fine:

```
=IF(AND(H3<>"", I3<>""), "ERROR", "OK")
```

However, I then tried to modify it to use `NOT(ISBLANK...)`:

```
=IF(NOT(AND(ISBLANK(H2), ISBLANK(I2))), "ERROR", "OK")
```

This doesn't work, but I can't figure out why.  I have two checks for blank cells, where the output is reversed by `NOT`, but the checks fail.  In my head I figured this formula would function as such:

```
Assuming ISBLANK(H2) = True and ISBLANK(I2) = True then...
=IF(NOT(AND(ISBLANK(H2), ISBLANK(I2))), "ERROR", "OK")
  equates to
=IF(NOT(AND(True, True)), "ERROR", "OK")
  equates to
=IF(NOT(True), "ERROR", "OK")
```

But that doesn't actually match the `IF` structure in Excel.  I've been staring at this far too long but I can't see which bit is actually broken...!

I modified the formula to this, which works fine:

```
=IF(AND(NOT(ISBLANK(H4)), NOT(ISBLANK(I4))), "ERROR", "OK")
```

Why does my first attempt fail?

Comment: `=IF(AND(NOT(ISBLANK(H4)), NOT(ISBLANK(I4))), "ERROR", "OK")` returns `OK`  here when `H4` has a value and `I4` is blank.  Maybe your `I4` has contents which only appears blank.  Or maybe you have calculation set to manual.

Comment: Hmm yes you're quite right.  I tested on a black sheet and it works.  There must be some issues relating to formula results being injected into the workings here.  Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here is that negation of `P ^ Q` is `!P V !Q`, according to the DeMorgan's Laws.  So your hypothetical formula:

```
=IF(NOT(AND(ISBLANK(H2), ISBLANK(I2))), "ERROR", "OK")
```

when negated actually becomes this:

```
=IF(OR(NOT(ISBLANK(H2)), NOT(ISBLANK(I2)))), "ERROR", "OK")
```

Note carefully that you are now ORing together the two middle terms, instead of ANDing them.  So your current formula using `ISBLANK` is actually correct:

```
=IF(AND(NOT(ISBLANK(H4)), NOT(ISBLANK(I4))), "ERROR", "OK")
```